OpenOCD Texas Instruments TMS570LC43x Configuration
I'm trying to flash my TMS570LC43x MCU board via OpenOCD. However, when I try to use the command flash I get and error showing various flash commands with the respective arguments.
I've tried using
flash write_image [myFile].bin

And got the message
flash
  flash bank bank_id driver_name base_address size_bytes chip_width_bytes
            bus_width_bytes target [driver_options ...]
  flash banks
  flash init
  flash list
  gdb flash_program ('enable'|'disable')
nand
program <filename> [address] [preverify] [verify] [reset] [exit]`

Does anyone know how to use OpenOCD to flash microcontrollers?
Thank you

Did you issue reset init before using flash programming commands?
